# Loop doesn't work when exported with ParcelJS

Tags: javascript, html, parceljs

I am using ParcelJS V2. I have the following code that gets data from an HTML table. Every `<td>` in the cell consists of an `<input>` tag and the `getElementById` refers to the ID of the input tag.

`getCount.js`

```
let rowCount = document.getElementById("left-col__table").rows.length;

let dataExport = []
let tuple = []

let i

function collectData() {

    for (i = 0; i < rowCount - 2; i++) {
        
        console.log("RowCount: " + rowCount)
        
        tuple.push(document.getElementById("x-in-" + i.toString()).value)
        tuple.push(document.getElementById("y-in-" + i.toString()).value)

        console.log(tuple);

        dataExport.push(tuple)

        tuple = []
    }

    console.log("DataExport:" + dataExport.toString())
}

export default collectData
```

`script.js`

```
import collectData from '....'

collectData()
```

When I check my console, there isn't log from the `collectData` function.

This `FOR` loop works fine when I use it in my `script.js` but doesn't work when I export and then import into `script.js`.

Are there any ways to export loops using ParcelJS?

Comment: can you please show us proper example of how you doing it cause this is not helping out.

Comment: @kunalpanchal I'm sorry it wasn't clear first. I tried clarifying further. Thanks

Comment: I don't think exporting a `function` that relies on the DOM being available at the time of the import is a good idea (`let rowCount = document.getElementById("left-col__table").rows.length;`). Move your variable declaration inside the function.

Comment: @connexo hi thanks for the tip. My function works now after I moved my variable into my function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move

```
let rowCount = document.getElementById("left-col__table").rows.length;
```

inside your `function collectData() {`.

At the time of bundling the DOM is unavailable, rendering your `rowCount` `undefined`.

When your function is being executed, your loop end condition checks

```
0 < undefined - 2
```

`undefined - 2` results in `NaN`.

```
0 < NaN
```

is `false`, so your loop never runs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.

### `getCount.js`

```
function collectData() {

  let rowCount = document.getElementById("left-col__table").rows.length;

  let dataExport = []
  let tuple = []

  let i

  for (i = 0; i < rowCount - 2; i++) {

    console.log("RowCount: " + rowCount)

    tuple.push(document.getElementById("x-in-" + i.toString()).value)
    tuple.push(document.getElementById("y-in-" + i.toString()).value)

    console.log(tuple);

    dataExport.push(tuple)

    tuple = []
  }

  console.log("DataExport:" + dataExport.toString())
}

export default collectData
```